# Can you use custom icons when creating lists using markdown?

Tags: markdown, font-awesome

I am using markdown to write a simple README.md for a github repo. In this document I have to create a list of items, and I was wondering if you can customize the icons used for the bullets of the list. For example, I would want to use a "-" as the icon instead of a "*". I would also be interested in knowing whether I can use a custom icon such as a fontawesome icon or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

In Markdown, it's impossible to do it out-of-the-box. You have to use a custom CSS. Check [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19656779/11147608) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be throughout the document? If so you might be able to use CSS against the `<li>` element.