# React replace li bullet with icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have found many answers that solve this with CSS or font awesome, however, I have an icon from https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=bi and I want to replace the li tag bullets with one of these icons.

I tried adding <IconName /> in front of each <li> but this doesn't look great and requires lots of styling and so was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: maybe this link will help you  https://dev.to/kevsmss/easiest-way-to-use-icons-in-react-h0o

Answer (score 2):

Create a class in your ul and then style your CSS as seen below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="sample">
<li>This is a list item</li>
<li>This is another list item</li>
<li>This is also another list item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.sample {
list-style-image: url('**your icon path **  icon_sample.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the icon is not an image it is a component I imported <IconName />

Comment: Ah I see, a little more complex for sure.... maybe this will help you out? It's for font awesome but could be applied to react icons as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468359/using-font-awesome-icon-for-bullet-points-with-a-single-list-item-element

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a **react-project** and I faced the same problem as you.
so i came up with this solution

The code below works for me in react, instead of using the image icon you can use this simple trick to get the job done.

**In CSS**

```
  ul{
    list-style : none;       // To remove bullet icon
    padding-left : 0.5rem;  // for decrease padding on left
  }
```

*You can also **use the specific class name** of course to avoid the styling the ul in your entire project*

**In JSX file**

```
  <ul>
      <li>
        <ImCancelCircle />     // To show the icon next to the msg
        <b>Error Message</b>  // Your msg
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**Hope this helps**